# Corrupt project VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Opening a solution (2 projects) in VS2012, I get several errors:

```
1. Unable to load one or more breakpoints.
2. Value does not fall within the expected range (opening web.config)
```

Looks something is corrupted. Is there an easy way to recover? Where are the breakpoints stored? Which value is (suddenly) out of range?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't know about fixing your Web.Config (Did you open an old project as a .NET 4.5 application?) but you can get rid of all the breakpoints with CTRL + SHIFT + F9 or Debug->Remove all breakpoints.

Comment: Remove all breakpoints (or CTRL + SHIFT + F9) doesn't work.

Comment: Try deleting your .suo file (resides in the same directory as the .sln file).

Comment: Thought about that option as well, but there are no .suo files. Got a lot of .sln files however. Is VS2012 using another mechanism to store that kind of data?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is still a (hidden) .suo file. Removing that file resolves BOTH problems!

Comment: If you are having trouble seeing hidden files, make sure you enable the option to view hidden files. Here's how to do this in Windows 7, for example: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7

Comment: In my case, deleting the .suo file in the root path of project directory didn't work. There was a hidden folder called ".vs" under which there was another .suo file which I had to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but Copying whole the VS project code into a new folder also solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find and delete **.suo** file from below correct place for Visual Studio 2015 project.

```
[Project Folder]\.vs\[Solution Name]\v14\.suo
```

I found the solution from here:

https://faalon.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/visual-studio-2015-suo-file-corrupt/